# Connection URL of phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, connection, phpmyadmin

Can any body help me to get the connection url of the MySQL database on the server of phpmyadmin. I want to access the database remotely.

Please note that the database is not on my local pc hard disk.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any programming language to perform the task?
Please be more clear.

Comment: Well, the domain is the domain where you access phpMyAdmin. The user and password... you know them... and the port is usually 3306. Try it like this :) .

Comment: @Dheeraj : Yes i want to use the database into an Web JSP application on netbeans using hibernate... plz help.

Comment: @SoboLAN : I know the port is 3306. i am using as jdbc:mysql://<mydomain ip>:3306/<DBName> But still i m getting the error. and i am not able to connect database remotely. plz help.

Comment: what's the error you are getting on connecting through url?

Comment: cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://69.187.151.5:3306/DCQ using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the connection URL for access Phpmyadmin MySql server:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//Set driver
connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db_ip:3306/dbName",user_name, password);
//Get Connection
```

If you got below message:

```
#1130 - Host 'machine name' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Then you need to execute below query:

```
   CREATE USER 'root'@'%';

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'%' ;

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `root\_%` . * TO 'root'@'%';
```

This query creates the root user with all privilege and password is null.

Edit:

This is the reference may help you:

https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

Comment: I am using the url : jdbc:mysql://69.187.151.5:3306/DCQ

But i am getting the error as i commented in my question.

Comment: I think this issues arises for mysql network permission. Refer this link [http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html]

Comment: m sorry to ask silly question, but can u tell me where to execute the above query.. Plz reply..

Comment: Open browser and type http://69.187.151.5/phpmyadmin. Click SQL tag. Copy and paste this query. Click Go to run.

Comment: i ll be back with results with actions as you said in 2 minutes.. thanks.. :)

Comment: i have already a user with root.. and but have some password.. Then what query should i execute.. plz reply the query with password.

Comment: I think no need to execute this queries for your problem. I have attached the link with the answer. Kindly refer it.

Comment: The link is quit confusing and the answer in the link says various points to check.. i am quit sure that every thing mentioned in the answer is perfect in my situation.. but yet i am getting this error.. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16350/discussion-between-dhina-karan-and-rambo)